# Cannot hit a WCF Service using SSL

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a WCF Service and its using SSL. I can compile and start the service.  However, I cannot hit it in the web browser. All it says is "The connection to 192.168.1.12 was interrupted." I made sure my browser has it enabled and it works on other sites using SSL. I'm new to WCF services so any advice or tips for troubleshooting would be helpful.

I am not using IIS**

Below is my web config information:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IApplicationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="6553600" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Application.ServiceModel.ApplicationService" behaviorConfiguration="ApplicationServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://192.168.1.12:8000/ApplicationServiceModel/service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IApplicationService" contract="Application.ServiceModel.IApplicationService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ApplicationServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: you should probably post the `<system.serviceModel>` element of your web.config, it may help people diagnose your problem

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345849/connection-interrupted-when-using-webhttpbinding-in-transport-securitymode

Comment: I already tried the tips in that MSDN article, it didnt help.

Comment: what server are you using then?

Comment: i went through and regenerated my ssl certificates and now I am getting the error "You attempted to reach 192.168.1.12, but the server presented an invalid certificate." when I try to hit it. It doesnt help much, but its at least more verbose than the last error.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self signed certificate is normally considered invalid, and only really used for test.

In wcf,  you can use the following to ignore certificate errors (on the client).

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

However, it should only be used for test.  In a production environment you want to get your certificate signed by a trusted cert authority.